# How to know which rules where used in the derivation of SAT result using fixed point engine of Z3?

Tags: z3

I'm using muZ engine of Z3. For all SAT cases I would like to see which rules where used in the derivation. Is there any way to extract this information?

For instance the input might look like this:

```
(declare-rel R1 (Int))
(declare-rel R2 (Int))
(declare-rel q (Int))

(declare-var n Int)

(rule (R1 n) rule_one)
(rule (=> (R1 n) (R2 n)) rule_two)
(rule (=> (and (R2 n) (< n 1)) (q n)) query)

(query q
:print-answer true
)
```

And I'd be glad to know which rules were triggered, something like

q is SAT, used rules: rule_one->rule_two->query

Comment: Could you kindly *edit* your question, explain better what kind of *rules* you have in mind and what is a *derivation* in this context for you? Although some  of *z3* devs and *expert* users might understand your question as is, personally, I do not. :)

Answer (score 0):

One can use the following option

```
(set-option :fixedpoint.generate_proof_trace true)
```